# Errorbar plot for pandas DataFrame shows weird items in the legend

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I use the latest version of the Anaconda package for Python 3.

- python: v3.4.3 (Anaconda 2.4.1)
- pandas: v0.17.1
- matplotlib: v1.5.0

I encountered a trouble, when I tried to plot data with errorbars mounted in pandas.DataFrame using matplotlib. Although data and errorbars were plotted correctly, an additional weird item whose name is a column name of y-axis data was added to the legend.

Here, I show a simple code demonstrating this weird behavior. Would you tell me how to remove this additional weird item in the legend?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create test data: here, y = 2x + e  
x = np.linspace(0,1,20)
y = 2*x + np.random.normal(size=20)
yerr = np.zeros(20)
yerr[:] = 1

# put data into DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame()
data["x"] = x
data["y"] = y
data["yerr"] = yerr

# plot test data
plt.errorbar(data["x"],data["y"],data["yerr"],
             ls="None",marker="o",label="test")
plt.legend(frameon=False,
           numpoints=1,
           loc="upper left")
plt.xlim(-0.05,1.05)
plt.show()
```

This code provides following figure in my python environment. You can see that there is an additional item "y" in the legend, which I'd like to remove.

[Output of the above sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V4MJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution just after posting this question; similar question was asked for [pandas.Series](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5393). This can be solved by specifying `barsabove=True` in pyplot.errorbar() as follows.

```
# plot test data
plt.errorbar(data["x"],data["y"],data["yerr"],
             barsabove=True,
             ls="None",marker="o",label="test")
```

This modification provides the following image.
[Output of the modified code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJgx1.png)